# await for proxy leads to get of 'then' property, what should I return?

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-proxy

I have a `Proxy` to mimic a virtual object. Getter of this proxy returns ready values.

I have discovered, that if the proxy is awaited, it leads to calling of the 'then' property of my proxy:

```
await myProxy
```

What should my proxy getter return in this situation? Is it a good idea to return the proxy itself, or a promise to itself?

Example is here:

https://jsfiddle.net/rv55Lpu1

What is confusing to me is that if I `await` an object, I get the object, but if I `await` a `Proxy`, it needs to have a 'then' property trap which returns itself.

Comment: the example you tried?or any sample proxy object to try?

Comment: Your question is lacking any detail, example, for anyone to really help.  Try creating a simple snippet for people to see the issue you mention.

Comment: example is here https://jsfiddle.net/rv55Lpu1/  What is confusing to me is that if I await an object, i got object, but if the object is simulated by proxy, it needs to have 'then' property trap which return itself.

Comment: its just return the value.you are not returning any promise here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider returning `undefined` or an object without a `then` method, because await calls `then` recursively until the resolved object has no more `then` method.

Take this example:

```js
(async () => {
    let p = new Proxy({ then: undefined }, {
        get: (target: any, prop: string, self: any) => {
            return (prop in target) ? target[prop] : (...args: any[]) => self;
        },
    });

    let example = await p.myChainable().awaitable().method();

    console.log("Result: ", example);
})();
```

It just returns `"Result: { then: undefined }`, because we return `self` in `(...args: any[]) => self` which would be replaced with your own logic of course.

If you replace the target `{ then: undefined }` with something else like `{ test: "abc" }` there will be no result at all, because the promise becomes never fulfilled and console.log will never be called at all.

So as a conclusion, no - I would not recommend returning the proxy object itself in the `then` method.